# maybeLoeb, and why does <<loop>> occur only sometimes / is it catchable?

Tags: haskell, exception, infinite-loop

I am playing around with loeb (https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md):

```
loeb :: Functor f => f (f a -> a) -> f a
loeb fs = xs where xs = fmap ($ xs) fs
```

and I want to write a function:

```
maybeLoeb :: Functor f => f (f a -> a) -> Maybe (f a)
```

that fails instead of entering an infinite loop when given bad input.

I am also having some difficulties understanding the behavior of the `<<loop>>` exception. I would like to catch it if possible.

When entered into GHCI:

```
loeb [(!! 1),(!! 0)] :: [Int]
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

However, when defined in loeb.hs:

```
main = print (loeb [(!! 1),(!! 0)] :: [Int])
```

And then loaded into GHCI with `:l main` we get:

```
*Main> :l loeb
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( loeb.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
[
```

And the program does not terminate.

Is the `<<loop>>` except catchable? If so, is there a way to get the second version above to throw the exception?

Comment: I fear you are trying to solve the halting problem. You might be able to catch <<loop>> (inside the `IO` monad), but in more complex cases GHC will actually loop instead of generating a catchable exception.

Comment: Your function takes as input any `Functor f => f (f a -> f)`, knowing nothing else, you know that all you can do with that value is `fmap` over it - producing some other `f b` for some `b`. This can *never* be of the form `Maybe (f c)` for any c. And there is no function which converts a general functor to a `Maybe` anything - there is simply no way to do so with a `Functor`. You may have more luck with `Traversable f => f (f a -> Maybe a) -> Maybe (f a)`? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<loop>>` exception exists because GHC's implementation of lazy evaluation, which was designed for *multi-threaded* operation, makes a very specific form of infinite loop easy to detect when using the *single-threaded* runtime system (RTS). When the multi-threaded RTS needs to force a thunk, it follows a procedure roughly like this:

1. Check if the thunk has been evaluated yet; if so, use the known value and ignore the rest of this.
2. Check if the thunk is marked as being in the process of evaluation. If so, the thread yields to let whatever thread is working on that thunk finish its job. Go back to step 0.
3. Mark the thunk to indicate it is being evaluated.
4. Evaluate the thunk.
5. Store the result and mark the thunk as evaluated.

The same basic procedure is used for both the single-threaded and multi-threaded runtimes, to avoid tremendous amounts of code duplication. But in the single-threaded runtime, the "yield" step is replaced by a `<<loop>>` exception—if the program tries to force a thunk in the process of forcing that very thunk, it is surely stuck. There surely isn't any other thread in the middle of forcing the thunk.

I'm not sure if the exception can be caught, but you certainly never want to *rely* on catching it—different optimization levels or compiler versions may produce the exception in different cases. The question of whether your program is stuck in an infinite loop cannot be answered in general. As [chi mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926604/maybeloeb-and-why-does-loop-occur-only-sometimes-is-it-catchable/33930554#comment55614889_33926604), this is called the *halting problem*, and Alan Turing famously proved it unsolvable.